# Create a custom tree structure with checkbox in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, tree, structure

I want to generate a custom tree structure using HTML and CSS in angular. I'm aware about similar feature available in angular material but I want to create my own. Features would be more/less similar to what material provides additionally I require some customization which would be easier.

The selection feature would be similar to the angular counterpart
for eg:-

1. If the main node is clicked to select all children below it gets selected
2. If a child sibling is clicked to select then its parent would be partially selected
3. If all children under a parent are clicked to select then parent gets selected
4. State of each node would be updated in the json itself or all selections would be retrieved by clicking another button

Thanks in advance

I created the following:

**Tree json**

```
{
    "tree": [{
            "name": "Parent 1",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "child 2",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 2",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Child 1",
                "children": []
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 3",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                },
        {
                    "name": "Child 4",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Subchild 1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subchild 2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 5",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Subchild 1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subchild 2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 6",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Subchild 1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subchild 2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 4",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }, {
                    "name": "Child 4",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Subchild 1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subchild 2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 5",
                    "children": [{
                            "name": "Subchild 1",
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subchild 2",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 5",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 6",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 7",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Parent 8",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Child 1",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 2",
                    "children": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "Child 3",
                    "children": [{
                        "name": "Subchild 1",
                        "children": []
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML Template**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
        <div class="chk-container" (click)="onParentClick($event, i)">
          <input id="{{ i }}" type="checkbox" />
          <label for="{{ i }}">{{ item.name }}</label>
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <div *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of item.children; let j = index">
              <div
                class="chk-container child hide"
                (click)="onChildClick($event, i, j)"
              >
                <input id="{{ i }}-{{ j }}" type="checkbox" />
                <label for="{{ i }}-{{ j }}">{{ item.name }}</label>
                <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div *ngIf="item.children.length > 0">
                  <ng-container
                    *ngFor="let item of item.children; let k = index"
                  >
                    <div
                      class="chk-container child hide"
                      (click)="onSubchildClick($event, i, j, k)"
                    >
                      <input id="{{ i }}-{{ j }}-{{ k }}" type="checkbox" />
                      <label for="{{ i }}-{{ j }}-{{ k }}">{{
                        item.name
                      }}</label>
                      <i
                        class="fa fa-angle-down"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        *ngIf="hasImmediateChildren(i, j, k) > 0"
                      ></i>
                    </div>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './custom-checkbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-checkbox.component.css']
})
export class CustomCheckboxComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() id: number;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() data: any = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addSpecialAttribs();
  }

  onParentClick($event: any, parentIndex: number) {
    this.hasChildren($event.target, parentIndex);
  }

  onChildClick($event: any, parentIndex: number, childIndex: number) {
    this.hasChildren($event.target, childIndex);
  }

  onSubchildClick($event: any, parentIndex: number, childIndex: number, subChildIndex: number) {
    this.hasChildren($event.target, subChildIndex);
  }

  traverseElements(targetEl: any) {
    console.log(targetEl.parentElement);
    console.log(targetEl.parentElement.children);
  }

  getJsonObject(parentIndex: number, childIndex?: number, subChildIndex?: number) {
    if (childIndex && subChildIndex) {
      console.log(this.data[parentIndex].children[childIndex].children[subChildIndex]);
    } else if (childIndex) {
      console.log(this.data[parentIndex].children[childIndex]);
    } else {
      console.log(this.data[parentIndex]);
    }
  }

  hasChildren(el: any, parentIndex: number) {
    console.log(this.data[parentIndex].children.length);
    // return this.data[parentIndex].children.length > 0;
  }

  onChange($event: any) {
    let tmp_arr = $event.target.id.split("-");
    let count = tmp_arr.length;
    if (count === 3) {
      console.log(this.data[tmp_arr[0]].children[tmp_arr[1]].children[tmp_arr[2]]);
    } else if (count === 2) {
      console.log(this.data[tmp_arr[0]].children[tmp_arr[1]]);
    } else {
      console.log(this.data[tmp_arr[0]]);
    }
  }

  addSpecialAttribs() {
    this.data.forEach((item: any) => {
      // if(item.)
    })
  }

  hasImmediateChildren(p: number, c: number, s: number) {
    return this.data[p]?.children[c]?.children[s]?.children.length;
  }

}
```

**CSS**

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
div > input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
div > input:checked + label {
  color: #e856a3;
}
div > input:checked + label::before {
  background: rgba(232, 86, 163, 0.25);
  border-color: #e856a3;
}
div > input:checked + label::after {
  transform: scale(1) rotate(-45deg);
}
div > input:checked + label a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div > label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
div > label::before {
  border: calc(1px + 0.06em) solid #4d4d4d;
  border-radius: calc(3px + 0.05em);
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  height: calc(3px + 0.8em);
  margin-right: calc(4px + 0.4em);
  transition: all 0.1s;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: calc(3px + 0.8em);
}
div > label::after {
  border-bottom: calc(2px + 0.07em) solid #e856a3;
  border-left: calc(2px + 0.07em) solid #e856a3;
  content: "";
  font-size: 1.1em;
  height: calc(3px + 0.22em);
  left: calc(0.25em - 1px);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 0.1em - 1px);
  transform: scale(0) rotate(-45deg);
  transition: all 0.1s;
  width: calc(5px + 0.32em);
}

.chk-container {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.chk-container label {
  width: 100%;
}

.chk-container i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 0;
}

.chk-container i.down {
  rotate: 80deg;
}

.chk-container.child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.hide {
  /* display: none; */
}
```